# What is the difference between ayumu, sanpo and aruku?

Tags: word-choice, usage, word-usage

I see three different words when I look up "walk".  Can someone explain why there are two and why one would be used instead of the other?

Comment: See also: [歩く vs 歩む](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2631/542)

Comment: And https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18000/7810

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Difference between ayumu, sanpo and aruku

*aruku* (歩｛ある｝く) is a general term for *to walk*.

*ayumu* (歩｛あゆ｝む) is a little old-fashioned expression for *to walk*, especially *to walk step by step*, and it has a unique and something moral meanings different from *aruku* such as *to make progress to a certain destination*.

As for *sanpo* (散歩｛さんぽ｝), it is a noun which means *a constitutional walk* or *a walk for relaxation*.
To make a *sanpo* (散歩｛さんぽ｝) a verb *suru* (する) is attached like *sanpo-suru* (散歩｛さんぽ｝する).